# Using CSS, how I can keep a block of white space from collapsing , even if there is no DIV element present?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following elements: Title, Description, and Image. There should be 20px space above the Title, like this:

[image: like this]

As you can see from the picture, there is a block of space above the title. I want the space to remain there, even if the Title and Description are not present. For example like this:

[image: like this]

Right now my problem is that, if there is no title and description, then the space is collapsing and the image is moving up and basically occupying that space.

How can I keep the space, even if there is no Title and Description present or not? I thought of applying `min-height` to the "titleName" , but that has not worked.

```
<div class="myComponent">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div id="head_Title" class="mainTitle">
    <h2 class="titleName"> This is a Title</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="description" class="mainDescription"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have an extra space in your first tag near <

Comment: If there is no title or description, then how can you know what the height of the space should be? Surely, that would vary depending on what text would be there.

Comment: there should always be a 20px space above the title. If there is no title, then there here should always be a 20px space above image.

Comment: Try adding `margin-top: 20px` to your `titleName`

Comment: CSS margin or padding maybe? If you want a quick hack, try <br><br> or <br><br><br>.

Comment: @firatozcevahir adding margin top will add extra space than there already is right?

Comment: @LeamSamuel Please show your full `html` and `css`. With given `html` example, it is impossible to know where that space comes from at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

If I am able to understand the question correctly, your problem would easily be solved by adding

```css
margin-top: 20px;
```

to `myComponent` class

Comment: No you didn't understand my question. If you add margin-top: 20px; then if there is title, it will get additional 20px space, which not what I want.  Regardless of whether there is title or not, I want 20px on top all the time.

Comment: Then remove that 20px margin from all other small components, like the title.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, when we remove the div, the entire div is removed from DOM element and also the space gets removed.

We can use the Visibility CSS property. When we use `visibility:hidden` property, the text content from div is hidden from the HTML DOM but not removed from the div tag.

You can also dynamically add a class that contains hidden property. The total space will be equivalent to the combined space of title and description.

I created a demo for reference with & without title and description, have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/alepsh/todenjsr

﻿